# Masonry grid in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to achieve a sort of masonry style grid, based on [this](https://medium.com/@andybarefoot/a-masonry-style-layout-using-css-grid-8c663d355ebb) article. I would like to implement it in a React component. For some reason, the styles do not apply. I am fairly new to react so I don't know if I am doing something wrong. The problem I have right now is that it seems that there is no css applied by my JS.

JS in React component

```
  // Also tried componentWillMount
  componentDidMount = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.resizeAllGridItems();
    }, 5000);
  }

  resizeGridItem = (item) => {
    let grid = document.getElementsByClassName("masonry-grid")[0];
    let rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
    let rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
    let rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));
    item.style.gridRowEnd = "span "+rowSpan;
  }

  resizeAllGridItems = () => {
    console.log('running..');
    let allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
    for(let x=0; x< allItems.length; x++){
       this.resizeGridItem(allItems[x]);
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
  <div className="masonry-grid">
    <div className="item one">
      <div className="content">1</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item two">
      <div className="content">2</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item three">
      <div className="content">3</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item four">
      <div className="content">4</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item five">
      <div className="content">5</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item six">
      <div className="content">6</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item seven">
      <div className="content">7</div>
    </div>
    <div className="item eight">
      <div className="content">8</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.masonry-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px,1fr));
}

.masonry-grid--item {

}

.one {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.two {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}
.three {
  height: 250px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.four {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.five {
  height: 220px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.six {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: purple;
}
.seven {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.eight {
  height: 140px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use, https://github.com/eiriklv/react-masonry-component.
This has a component built-in with Masonry.

Comment: I am working on a version in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/9l4o308kjo

Comment: As I normally use other components, I would like to fix this issue so I can build something to my own preferences